# How to create javascript file dynamically using c#?

Tags: c#

I would like to create javascript file dynamically using c#.

Below is my javascript formatted data :

```
var statesData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama","density":94.65},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}}
]};
```

I tried to copy the above codes and paste it into .aspx.cs file i am getting red marked error.

How can i create javascript structured format and create the .js file as dynamically.

Please help me to solve.

Comment: what you're noticing is that javascript is not the same language as C#. What is your question?

Comment: did you embed that code within the script tag? would help if you show the actual and complete code where your are getting the error

Comment: Dhamo, do you want to create a .js file or a JSON file, because what you are showing us is JSON, not javascript.

Comment: that is json file format but i tried to create json file within js

Answer (score 1):

```
private void CreateJS(string jsPath, string[] contents)
{
    File.Create(jsPath)
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(jsPath);

    foreach (string s in contents)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

This would create a file at the specified path, and write the contents of a string array to the file.

So you'd just pass it something like this;

```
CreateJS(@"C:\myFile.js", myStringArray);
```

And just divvy up your data into the array.

That said, while this answers "How do I create a javascript file dynamically?" I don't think this is actually what you're looking to do.